# Determining Current Window Dimensions

Tags: android, css, html

I'm currently designing a responsive website which adjusts to all types of screen sizes. Even though my content is set out in percentages, when I view it on various tablets it's out of position.

Is there such a way when I shrink my desktop screen that it can tell me which pixel dimensions that I'm looking at so I can make better scaling solutions? I've searched for an app but no look. Sorry for wasting your time if this is a amateur question.

Really appreciate any advice, Thanks

Comment: take a look on this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: and this if you meant checking the size from website : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/how-to-get-web-page-size-browser-window-size-screen-size-in-a-cross-browser-wa

Comment: Thank you loads great info page, It has exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks Saif